# onClick Causing Crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My app crashes when I press any of the two buttons I have added, i.e. bAdd and bSubtract.  This is like the second app I have written by following a few tutorials, so this is completely new to me.  "xxx" and "yyy" are called when the bSubtract and bAdd buttons are pressed, which then causes the app to crash on my phone. xml, code and logcat shown below.

xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myapp1.CalculateActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSubtract"
        android:onClick="xxx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bAdd"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bAdd"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bAdd"
        android:text="@string/bSubtract" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAdd"
        android:onClick="yyy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/bAdd" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
public class CalculateActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int counter;
    TextView display;
    Button add, sub;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculate);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        counter = 0;
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
    * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
    */

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() { }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculate,
                      container, false);
              return rootView;
        }
    }


    public void xxx(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        counter--;
        display.setText(""+ counter);

    }


    public void yyy(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        counter++;
        display.setText(""+ counter);

    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
04-16 23:07:04.409: D/AndroidRuntime(22562): Shutting down VM
04-16 23:07:04.409: W/dalvikvm(22562): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418db700)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    ... 11 more
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at com.example.myapp1.CalculateActivity.yyy(CalculateActivity.java:83)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    ... 14 more
04-16 23:12:14.494: I/Process(22562): Sending signal. PID: 22562 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Make sur your views are inside `activity_calculate`.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at com.example.myapp1.CalculateActivity.yyy(CalculateActivity.java:83)` what is line 83?  Oh, and learn how to use the debugger.  Then you could find this error in 30 seconds.

Comment: The layout xml that you have posted: Is it `fragment_calculate` or `activity_calculate`?

Comment: Hint: you can change the value of the attribute `layout_alignBottom` to `@id/` instead of '@+id/' to use a predefined id instead of creating new one,  and make sure that the id you will use is defined before calling it. this will prevent making a relative relation to a non existing id.

Comment: try to initialize the PlaceholderFragment after the initialization of `display`

Comment: Guys thanks for the response; and to Caue as well for his response below.  I took the advice and learnt how to use the debugger.  The problem was caused by the 'display' textview I initialized in the onCreate method.  When I called the onclick methods 'xxx' and 'yyy' in response to the button presses, I did not reinitialize 'display', but I tried to set its text using .settext.  This caused the nullpointerexception.

Comment: I re-initialised the 'display' textview inside the xxx and yyy methods, and then called settext.  This solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Buttons add and sub are null. Try the following code (add in onCreate()):

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```

Comment: NPE is thrown in `yyy` method according stacktrace.

Comment: Agree with donfuxx. I saw neither `add` or `sub` variable inside `yyy` method.

Comment: My bad. I read "..I press any of the two buttons I have added..." and assumed NPE is caused there.

Comment: Thanks araut.  You were on the right track.  See my response above.

Comment: Looks like one of the widgets was causing NPE - there are multiple solutions to a problem; Do look at what donfuxx and @Fllo have mentioned. Their track for solution seems to be more clean and clear.

Answer (score -2):

You've created your buttons at xml but haven't added the reference, this should help you. Add it before you start using it.

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```

You could also instead add the reference from your listeners at your xml as you have done

```
 android:onClick="xxx"
 android:onClick="yyy"
```

You can add it programmatically, like this.

```
add.setOnClickListener(xxx);

 View.OnClickListener xxx = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something in response to button
            counter--;
            display.setText(""+ counter);
        }
    };
```

I believe that this depends entirely on you.
Also, check your log, it says your button is null; it pretty much says what's going wrong.

```
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    at com.example.myapp1.CalculateActivity.yyy(CalculateActivity.java:83)
04-16 23:07:04.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22562):    ... 14 more
```

Anyhow, just remember to add the reference to your views before doing anything with then.. That should avoid future null pointers exceptions.

Comment: First: I can't find in the log where it says that the `Button` is null, Second: calling the function from xml or Java i don't think will solve except if there is a problem with the eclipse and cannot build the program !!

Comment: Try to initialise both your buttons as I've said. I've quoted in the log where you can find out that your button is null.

Comment: NPE is thrown in yyy method according stacktrace